# mysql_fetch_row not returning full array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am attempting to loop through rows in MySQL with the following code.  Unfortunately, the `mysql_fetch_row` function is only returning the first row of my query (I confirmed this with print_r).  When I use `mysql_num_rows`it returns the correct number of rows for that query(2).  Any idea why `mysql_fetch_row` is returning only the first row?

```
$query = 'SELECT firstName FROM profiles WHERE city="Phoenix" and lastName ="Smith"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row); //This returns only 1 array item: Array ( [0] => John)

$a=mysql_num_rows($result);
print_r($a); //This returns 2
```

I have also run the same query in MySQL and it returns both rows ("John" and "Jim").

Thanks for the help.

Comment: thanks for the responses. forgot that mysql_fetch_row only returns 1 row at a time.  using a while loop worked perfect.

Comment: If a specific answer provided this answer for you, you should mark that answer as accepted (click the green checkbox to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just perform `mysql_fetch_row` twice (or in a loop). By definition (if you read the documentation) it returns only one row at once. So:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to put it in a [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   $firstName = $row['firstName'];

   echo("$firstName<br />");

}
```

What this does is for each result (row) it finds, it fetches the data you want and displays it. So it gets the first result, displays the name, loops back to the top, fetches the second result, displays that name and so on, then once you have no more results that match the query criteria, the while loop is ended.

Comment: Why do you put `"` around the variable name? `echo $firstName;` is shorter and more readable

Comment: Bad habits more than anything :/

Answer (score 1):

PHP accesses the SQL Results in order of how they're buffered. You'll need to run a loop to access all the contents.

If you wish to load everything into an array:

```
$allRows=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
  $allRows[]=$row;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is a best idea to say about "buffered". The results are accessed in the order mysql returned them - that's imho better

Comment: The mysql_query() function will buffer all the results first before providing access to the PHP handle. The mysql_unbuffered_query() will provide access as soon as the first row is available and will then when subsequent rows are available. This is what I meant by how they're buffered.

Comment: as I said - there is no reason to even mention about **current php implementation**. Tomorrow it *can be changed*. What will not change is the statement that "the data is returned in the exact order mysql return it"

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following one:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   echo $row['firstName'];
}
```

or

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   echo $row['firstName'];
}
```

or

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
{
    echo $row->firstName;
}
```